# Impossible to build vuejs app - pagination error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to paginate an array in my vue.js app component. When I try to build it I get an error from the vue ui output console:

```
warning  Replace `·class="page-item"·v-for="(item,·index)·in·onlineCams"·:key="index"·v-if="index·>=·perpage·*·(n-1)·&&·index·<·perpage·*·n"` with `⏎··············class="page-item"⏎··············v-for="(item,·index)·in·onlineCams"⏎··············:key="index"⏎··············v-if="index·>=·perpage·*·(n·-·1)·&&·index·<·perpage·*·n"⏎············`  prettier/prettier
  193:84  error    The 'onlineCams' variable inside 'v-for' directive should be replaced with a computed property that returns filtered array instead. You should not mix 'v-for' with 'v-if'
```

I'm using this code but it will not work. How I can fix it?

HTML for pagination

```
      <div
        class="col-1 text-center p-0 feed-col"
        v-for="(cam, idx) in onlineCams"
        :key="idx"
      >
        <img class="img-fluid w-100 h-100" :src="cam.image_url_360x270" />
        <div class="card-img-overlay p-0">
          <a
            class="text-white text-decoration-none stretched-link"
            target="_blank"
            :href="cam.chat_room_url_revshare"
          ></a>
        </div>
        <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
          <ul class="pagination" v-for="n in pages" :key="n">
            <li class="page-item" v-for="(item, index) in onlineCams" :key="index" v-if="index >= perpage * (n-1) && index < perpage * n">
              <a class="page-link" href="#">{{ index }}</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
```

JS code

```
<script>
export default Vue.extend({
  name: "Index",
  data() {
    return {
      onlineCams: [],
      perPage: 50
    };
  },
  mounted() {
      // other code for update data here
  },
  computed: {
    // cam pagination
    length() {
      return this.onlineCams.length
    },
    pages() {
      return Math.ceil( this.length / this.perPage )
    }
  },
  methods: { /* other code to fetch data here */ }
}); // end vue
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using v-if and v-for together is not recommended, see this link: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-with-v-for

You must replace it for a computed property.

Or you can try somethig like this:

```html
<li class="page-item" v-for="(item, index) in onlineCams" :key="index">
  <template v-if="index >= perpage * (n-1) && index < perpage * n">
    <a class="page-link" href="#">{{ index }}</a>
  </template>
</li>
```

PS - Answer of your comment:
If you want to create a simple pagination, you can see this code as example:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div>{{ itemsPaginate }}</div>
    <div>
      <button @click="currentPage++">next page</button>
      <button @click="currentPage--">prior page</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data: () => ({
    items: [
      { id: 1, name: 'Test' },
      { id: 2, name: 'Test' },
      { id: 3, name: 'Test' },
      { id: 4, name: 'Test' },
      { id: 5, name: 'Test' },
      { id: 6, name: 'Test' },
      { id: 7, name: 'Test' },
      { id: 8, name: 'Test' },
      { id: 9, name: 'Test' },
      { id: 10, name: 'Test' },
    ],
    currentPage: 1,
    itemsByPage: 3,
  }),
  computed: {
    itemsPaginate() {
      let result = [];
      let init = (this.currentPage - 1) * this.itemsByPage;
      for (let i = init; i < this.items.length; i++) {
        result.push(this.items[i]);
        if (result.length >= this.itemsByPage) {
          break;
        }
      }
      return result;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

If you need the others options you can add.

Comment: I know, but I followed an example found here on SO. Anyway, I'm not able to paginate the data, the navigation for the pagination isn't displayed, I think that the code I've used is completely wrong. I have a 100 items array to paginate every 25 items but I'm a noob with javascript so I don't know where to start with.

Comment: I update my answer with a simple pagination. Are you looking for it?

Comment: I'm reading the updated answer, I need to test the code, thanks for the suggestion. If this can help, the `onlineCams` variable is composed from objects. What I want to do is use the bootstrap 4 pagination, as I understand I need first to know the lenght of the array, then make some calculation to split items in pages right?

Comment: You need to know: number of current page and length of rows by page. Then make the calculation to split items in pages.

Comment: Ok, so starting from my actual code, what I need to fix or implement to make bootstrap pagination working correctly in the component? I saw many examples, but I'm a noob in javascript so I'm not really able to fix the code at all

Comment: First, you must to make pagination without `css bootstrap`, with simple buttons. After then you apply the style with `css bootstrap`. I believe that software development must following this steps: 1 - Do it works / 2 - Do it beatiful / 3 - Do it fast.

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem? Please accept this answer and this will help others people. [How to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

Probbably, you've mixed Typescript with pure JS.
Some fixes:

```html
  <div
        class="col-1 text-center p-0 feed-col"
        v-for="(cam, idx) in onlineCams"
        :key="idx"
      >
        <img class="img-fluid w-100 h-100" :src="cam.image_url_360x270" />
        <div class="card-img-overlay p-0">
          <a
            class="text-white text-decoration-none stretched-link"
            target="_blank"
            :href="cam.chat_room_url_revshare"
          ></a>
        </div>
        <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
          <ul class="pagination" v-for="n in pages" :key="n">
            <li class="page-item" v-for="(item, index) in onlineCams" :key="index" v-if="index >= perpage * (n-1) && index < perpage * n">
              <a class="page-link" href="#">{{ index }}</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
```

````html
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'; // Added this line

export default Vue.extend({
  name: "Index",
  data() {
    return {
      onlineCams: [],
      perPage: 50
    };
  },
  mounted() {
      // other code for update data here
  },
  computed: {
    // cam pagination
    length() {
      return this.onlineCams.length
    },
    pages() {
      return Math.ceil( this.length / this.perPage )
    }
  },
  methods: { /* other code to fetch data here */ }
}); // end vue
</script>
```
````

Comment: I'm using vue cli with the ui version, I've chosen to use typescript but it was a mistake during the project configuration. Anyway the problem is with the pagination that I need to understand how to

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of full client-side pagination, filtering and sorting which you can adapt for your needs:

```js
//
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      items: [],
      search: '',
      sort: {
        col: 'id',
        desc: false
      },
      paging: {
        page: 1,
        pages: [],
        perPage: 5,
        totalItems: 0,
        totalItemsFiltered: 0,
        next: function() {
          this.page++
        },
        back: function() {
          --this.page
        },
      },
    }
  },
  watch: {
    'paging.perPage': function() {
      this.computePaging()
    },
    items: function() {
      this.computePaging()
    },
  },
  computed: {
    filtereditems() {
      let items = this.items.filter(item => {
        return (
          item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
          item.body.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) > -1
        )
      })
      return (this.paging.page != -1 ?
        this.paginate(items, this.paging.perPage, this.paging.page) :
        items
      ).sort((a, b) => {
        if (a[this.sort.col] < b[this.sort.col]) return this.sort.desc ? -1 : 1
        if (a[this.sort.col] > b[this.sort.col]) return this.sort.desc ? 1 : -1
        return 0
      })
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getItems()
  },
  methods: {
    getItems() {
      //https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts
      fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", {
          "headers": {
            "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
            "accept-language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
            "cache-control": "max-age=0",
          },
          "method": "GET",
          "mode": "cors",
          "credentials": "include"
        }).then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => this.items = data);
    },
    computePaging() {
      //
      this.paging.pages = []
      this.paging.totalItems = this.items.length
      //
      for (
        let i = 1; i <=
        Math.ceil(
          (this.paging.totalItemsFiltered =
            this.items.filter(item => {
              return (
                item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
                item.body.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) > -1
              )
            }).length / this.paging.perPage)
        ); i++
      ) {
        this.paging.pages.push(i)
      }
    },
    paginate(array, page_size, page_number) {
      --page_number
      return array.slice(page_number * page_size, (page_number + 1) * page_size)
    },
    setSort(col) {
      this.paging.page = 1
      this.sort = {
        col,
        desc: this.sort.col === col ? !this.sort.desc : false
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
/*ignore - hide snippets console */

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.14/vue.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="app">

  <input class="form-control" v-model="search" placeholder="Filter posts..." />

  <table class="table table-sm">
    <tr>
      <th @click="setSort('id')">
        <span v-if="this.sort.col === 'id'">{{ sort.desc ? '▲' : '▼'}}</span>ID
      </th>
      <th @click="setSort('userId')">
        <span v-if="this.sort.col === 'userId'">{{ sort.desc ? '▲' : '▼'}}</span>User Id
      </th>
      <th @click="setSort('title')">
        <span v-if="this.sort.col === 'title'">{{ sort.desc ? '▲' : '▼'}}</span>Title
      </th>
      <th @click="setSort('body')">
        <span v-if="this.sort.col === 'body'">{{ sort.desc ? '▲' : '▼'}}</span>Body
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr v-for="(item, index) in filtereditems" :key="index">
      <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.userId }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.title }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.body }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <div class="row no-gutters" style="background-color: #fafafa;">
    <div class="col p-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        Per Page:
        <select class="custom-select ml-1" v-model="paging.perPage" style="width:100px">
          <option>5</option>
          <option>10</option>
          <option>25</option>
          <option>50</option>
          <option>100</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col p-2">
      <ul class="pagination float-right" v-if="items.length > 0">
        <li class="page-item pagination-prev" :class="{'disabled': paging.page == 1 }">
          <a class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0)" @click="() => { paging.back() }">
            <span>&laquo;</span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <template v-for="pageNumber in paging.pages">
              <li
                class="page-item"
                v-if="Math.abs(pageNumber - paging.page) < 5 || pageNumber === paging.pages.length || pageNumber === 1"
                :class="{
                active: paging.page === pageNumber,
                last: (pageNumber === paging.pages.length && Math.abs(pageNumber - paging.page) > 5),
                first:(pageNumber === 1 && Math.abs(pageNumber - paging.page) > 5)
              }"
                @click="() => { paging.page = pageNumber }"
                :key="'pn-'+pageNumber"
              >
                <a class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0)">{{ pageNumber }}</a>
              </li>
            </template>
        <li class="page-item pagination-next" :class="{'disabled': paging.page === paging.pages.length}">
          <a class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0)" @click="() => { paging.next() }">
            <span>&raquo;</span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ideally, if you can implement paging, sorting and filtering server-side its much simpler then as the app can simply set params like `?page=1&sort=id&desc=1&search=abc` then you only need run computePaging on items array which will calculate the pagination dom.

Comment: Nice snippet. For the server side pagination, I don't have access to the server, I'm using an api to get the informations about webcams that are online so I'm not able to control how the data are provided by the server.